# How can i initialize constant with derived values in HLSL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I'm trying to migrate [this glsl code](https://ebruneton.github.io/precomputed_atmospheric_scattering/atmosphere/definitions.glsl.html) into hlsl (unity shader). But the compiler complains about the following lines:

```
#define Length float
const Length m = 1.0;
const Length km = 1000.0 * m;
```

where `km` is derived from `m`, and the error msg said:

*'km': initial value must be a literal expression*

Is there any way to solve this without just replacing `m` with its literal value manually?

I tried to google this but found nothing related, or maybe this question is just a complaint about HLSL's weak compiler.

Comment: [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/in-hlsl-what-is-the-difference-between-static-const-and-define-for-constan) might be of interest

Answer (score 0):

According to [glsl-to-hlsl-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/glsl-to-hlsl-reference), we should use `static const` qualifiers in hlsl.